# How to read JSON using $.parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

It feels like I'm posting a duplicate but I just can't find a satisfactory answer.
I've got a JSON object that I've parsed and it looks like:

```
var jsonresp = $.parseJSON(response);

jsonresp = 
{
  "success": true,
  "resource": {
    "street": "the address",
    "house_number": number,
    "postcode": "postcode",
    "town": "city",
  }
}
```

Now if I'm correct a square bracket means that it's an object. But what does a curly bracket represent?

Let's say I want to get the value of street, why does `jsonresp.resource.street` return undefined? In other words what are the contents of the resource between the curly brackets and how should I select them?

EDIT: thanks for all the reactions. It seems like something else is going wrong.

So this is the code I use:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, postretrieve, function(response) {
    var jsonresp = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(jsonresp);
    var jsonresp2 = {"success":true,"resource":{"street":"streetname","house_number":20,"postcode":"postcode","town":"city"}};
    console.log(jsonresp2.resource.street);
}
```

I exactly copy paste what is in jsonresp and make that a second variable jsonresp2. `jsonresp2.resource.street` returns the correct value but `jsonresp.resource.street` gives an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT2:
I was json_encoding my output file in php that was already json_encoded, thanks for the help!

Comment: Felix put an answer for one of those, let me find it.

Comment: `Now if I'm correct a square bracket means that it's an object` that is incorrect. square bracket is an array. However, your `jsonresp.resource.street` should have given you the value. http://jsfiddle.net/6fYag/

Comment: `jsonresp.resource.street` should work for that object (note I had to change `number` to something defined): http://jsfiddle.net/5Sbw3/

Comment: If `jsonresp.resource.street` does't give you the value you expect, then the structure of the object is not what you posted here. `console.log` each nested property (step by step) and inspect the value to find out how you have to access it.

Comment: What is `response`?  What does `console.log(jsonresp);` show?

Comment: if `jsonresp.resource.street` returns undefined then your `jsonresp` variable doesn't look like you think it does

Answer (score 1):

This is basic javascript: a `{...}` (curly braces) defines an object literal and a `[...]` (square braces) defines an array.  If you have

```
var myObj = {
   someProperty: 'property value'
};
```

`myObj.someProperty  // evaluates to 'property value'`

or

`myObj['someProperty'] // evaluates to 'property value'`

As is mentioned in your the comments to your question, if the `jsonresp.resource.street` code returns undefined, then your json structure is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try `jsonresp.resource.street` again after putting number in quotes.

```
jsonresp = 
{
  "success": true,
  "resource": {
    "street": "the address",
    "house_number": "number",
    "postcode": "postcode",
    "town": "city",
  }
}
```